# How do I understand the ratios between $\pi_1(U(N))=\mathbb{Z}$, $\pi_1(U(1))=\mathbb{Z}$, and $\pi_1(PSU(N))=\mathbb{Z}/N$?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homotopy-theory, exact-sequence

We know that $$\pi_1(SU(N))=0, \tag{1}$$
$$\pi_1(PSU(N))=\pi_1(SU(N)/(\mathbb{Z}/N))=\pi_0(\mathbb{Z}/N)=\mathbb{Z}/N.\tag{2}$$

Also that
$$\pi_1(U(N))=\pi_1(\frac{SU(N)\times U(1)}{\mathbb{Z}/N})=\mathbb{Z}.\tag{3}$$
$$\pi_1(U(1))=\mathbb{Z}.\tag{4}$$

--

> **My question** is that how do I visualize the $\pi_1(U(N))=\mathbb{Z}'$ versus the $\pi_1(U(1))=\mathbb{Z}$? Is that the intervals of $\pi_1(U(N))=\mathbb{Z}'$ $N$ times larger or smaller than $\pi_1(U(1))=\mathbb{Z}$? How to visualize the ratios?

--

We learn from the long exact sequence of homotopy groups that
$$
\pi_1(\mathbb{Z}/N)=0 \to \pi_1(SU(N)\times U(1))=\mathbb{Z} \to  \pi_1(U(N)) \to
\pi_0(\mathbb{Z}/N)=\mathbb{Z}/N \to \pi_0(SU(N)\times U(1))=0 \to \dots
$$
So we have $$0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \pi_1(U(N)) \to\mathbb{Z}/N \to 0.$$
So it seems
$$
\frac{\pi_1(U(N))}{\pi_1(SU(N)\times U(1))}
=\frac{\pi_1(U(N))}{\pi_1(  U(1))}=
\frac{\mathbb{Z}'}{\mathbb{Z}}=\mathbb{Z}/N=\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{N\mathbb{Z}}=\frac{\mathbb{Z}/N}{\mathbb{Z}}.
$$

Comment: $\pi_1U_n$ is generated by the loop $\alpha$ given by $S^1\ni\lambda\mapsto diag(\lambda,0,\dots,0)\in U_n$. The projective group $PU_n$ is the quotient of $U_n$ by its centre, which is the group $S^1$ sitting along the diagonal as the matrices $diag(\lambda,\dots,\lambda)$, $\lambda\in S^1$. The map $\beta:\lambda\mapsto diag(\lambda,\dots,\lambda)$ is thus the kernel of the projection $U_n\rightarrow PU_n$. It's easy to see that $\beta\simeq n\cdot\alpha$.